# Initialize Multiple Variables JSON in Power Automate

Tags: json, variables, power-automate

I'm working on populate a MS Word Template in Power Automate and all responses come from a MS Form.  One of the fields in the Word Template is "Abbreviation". I'm trying to figure out a way to pass the dynamic variable of "What is your County" into this field and convert the specific county name into the County abbreviation. Example would be "Washington County": "WC". I thought about using JSON object to do this but can't figure out how to connect the dynamic variable of "What is your County" to each County and County Abbreviation. I've got some screenshots of what I am working on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So if I’m understanding you correctly, dynamically, you want to pull the value of a property in an object by using the value of another variable as the name of the property you want to get the value for? If so, yes, that’s possible. Will try and get you answer soon, it’s early here. 

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I’m trying to make a statement like this to work, if “What is your County” response is “Washington County”, then “Washington County” abbreviates to “WC”, and that would go into abbreviate field of the populate word template. I have 25 counties to do that for and depending on which is entered I’d like the correct abbreviation to go into the template field. Take your time! Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite straight forward.  Using expression, you can pass in the value of a variable into an expression that will retrieve the value of a property in another object.

This example shows you how to achieve what you're after.

[image: Flow]

Basically, I've created an object with a set of properties.  I've then created a variable who's value is the name of the one of the properties in the object created in the previous step.

Then in the final step, using this expression ...

```
variables('Lookup Object')?[variables('Lookup Property')]
```

I can get the value, like thus ...

[image: Result]

If I were to hardcode that expression and be specific, it would look like this ...

```
variables('Lookup Object')?['Property 2']
```

... and that’s what you’re trying to avoid.

Comment: Hey Skin- Thanks for answering this one so quickly. I won’t be able to test this but I’m certain this is what I need! As always, appreciate the help. Very useful for future flows as well!